# Error using singular form of model as a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model "affiliate" and using the resources for `resources :affiliates`

I want to have a page site/affiliate so I added `get '/affiliate', to: 'affiliates#affiliate'` to  `routes.rb`

When I go to `/affiliate` it shows a form and when I go to `/affiliates` it lists the affiliates. But now, every time I call `@affiliate` it changes the address to `/affiliate.id` example: When i click on the link show `<td><%= link_to 'Show', affiliate %></td>` it goes to the singular form .id instead of plural /id  `/affiliate.5`

Is that a way to fix or I will have to change the view `/affiliate` to something different?

Comment: Your problem is that when you use a record `affiliate` in `link_to`, it doesn't go to `affiliate_path`, but `/affiliate`?

Comment: I have `@affiliates.each do |affiliate| `  that's why I have `link_to 'Show', affiliate`. when I click on the show in the browser it goes to `/affiliate.4` 4 being the id of the affiliate. It is weird because it doesn't even use `/`, it uses a period and the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a record in `link_to`, Rails need to figure out the path from the record. One of the things it does is to call `to_param`, which gives the id of the record by default. Usually it'll be able to match `/affiliates/id`. But the matching is not unique, and it can match some other possibilities too (I'm not sure about all the possible matches when a url is extracted from a record). What's important is that Rails will take the first matching route. In your case it is able to match `/affiliate.id` first since you have

`get '/affiliate', to: 'affiliates#affiliate'`

It's a legitimate url, with `id` as the format.

One thing you can do is to move this route after `resources :affiliates` in routes.rb, so Rails will match `affiliate_path` first. Or just use the named route in your `link_to` to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't understand that the order in the routes.rb was that important. I can understand now why I had so many problems in the past too. By changing the `resources` before `get` it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for explaining how it actually works so I get to learn.

Comment: No problem. We're all here to learn. You should read [Rails' guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', affiliate_path %></td>
```

or

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show','/affiliate' %></td>
```

Reason being your have mentioned `resources :affiliates` which generates url as per REST so

```
affiliates GET   /affiliates(.:format)    affiliates#index
```

so when you go `/affiliates` it will go to `index` action which gives you lists of `affiliates`